# How to fill an array from user's input in terminal with readline() in JavaScript? (no web)

Tags: javascript, arrays, vector, readline

From a program where the user gives some values in a terminal and then I work with that info like:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("number 1: ", function(one) {
    rl.question("number 2: ", function(two) {
        rl.question("number 3: ", function(three) {
            if (one > two && one > three) {
                console.log("bigger: " + one);
            } else if (two > one && two > three) {
                console.log("bigger: " + two);
            } else {
                console.log("bigger: " + three);
            }
            rl.close();
        });
    });
});

rl.on("close", function() {
    console.log("\nBYE BYE !!!");
    process.exit(0);
});
```

I want to do something similar: Get user's input from terminal with readline() and fill an array[10], something like:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

var vector = new Array(10);


for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
    rl.question("value " + (i+1) + ": ", function(one) {
        temp = parseInt(one);
        vector.splice(i, 0, temp);
    });
    if (i = vector.length) {
        rl.close();
    };
};

rl.on("close", function() {
var biggest = Math.max.apply(null, vector);
var smallest = Math.min.apply(null, vector);
console.log("biggest " + biggest + " and smallest " + smallest);
process.exit(0);
});
```

Any tip?

Comment: Does it work? Is there an issue? What's the question? Stackoverflow is more about troubleshooting. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better suited for improving working code.

Comment: @Ouroborus "How to fill an array from user's input in terminal with readline() in JavaScript?" sounds like the OP is asking for code, not asking to improve correctly working code. And so is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Actually it was a bit of both, to know what was wrong in my code and how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.question()` is largely asynchronous. It's given a callback (which is executed at some unknown time in the future) and returns immediately. So the rest of your code goes about its business without waiting.

One possible way of dealing with this:

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const vector = new Array(10);

const handleResults = function(index, vector, answer) {
  // process the answer
  vector[index] = parseInt(answer);

  // start the next question
  index++;
  if(index < vector.length) {
    // ask next question
    rl.question("value " + index + ": ", handleResults.bind(this, index, vector));
  }
  else {
    // we're done, wrap things up
    rl.close();
  }
};

rl.on("close", function() {
  var biggest = Math.max.apply(null, vector);
  var smallest = Math.min.apply(null, vector);
  console.log("biggest " + biggest + " and smallest " + smallest);
  process.exit(0);
});

// Start the questions
rl.question("value 0: ", handleResults.bind(this, 0, vector));
```

Another (possibly better) option is to use promises. However, I'll leave that to another answerer.